# Div inline-block display and proper position after using transform: scale

Tags: jquery, css, scale, css-transforms, display

At the beginning I'd like to say sorry for my english - I'm trying to do my best ;)

Here is what I managed to create:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/27uxtcc5/11/)

What I'm trying to do is to scale div that contains few different elements by using js, but at the same time I do want to keep the inline-block display, so after scaling more (or less, depending ont the scale value) elements could fit in one row.

Html of just one element looks like this:

```
<div class="containerofelements">
 <div class="resizeratio">1</div>
 <div class="resizeratio">0.75</div>
 <div class="resizeratio">0.5</div>
 <hr />
 <div class="elements" style="background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/ha1wAo/back.png)">
   <div class="middle">middle</div>
   <div class="leftup">leftup</div>
   <div class="rightup"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/dK2BRT/profile_default_m.jpg" /></div>
   <div class="leftdown">leftdown</div>
   <div class="rightdown">rightdown</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The ammount of elements will be variable, and most likely there will be more different content inside the ".elements" div.
The `.resizeratio` divs are buttons that scales `.elements` by the written value by using jquery.

I was able to successfully scale elements and keep position of all child elements by js by using code:

```
css({
 transform: "scale("+scale+")"
});
```

Unfortunately, after scaling the div does keep original position. As I managed to notice, the div itself is scaled, but it somehow does not change position, just like the empty space after scaling element down is filled by additional margin. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick fix for you

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/27uxtcc5/14/)

Just add a div (for example `.wrap`) around `.elements` and change its width and height depending on scale like this.

```css
el.parent('.wrap').css({
  width: (350 * scale) + "px",
  height: (500 * scale) + "px"
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.elements {
  width: 340px;
  height: 490px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 5px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the css property zoom, but that wouldn't work in Firefox.

Another solution would be to use negative left and right margin.

If that doesn't work, you should have a look at the flexbox property.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/